# the filename of pdf file doesnt work correctly with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: django, filenames, wkhtmltopdf

I have a button download in my Django project, where I can export the report for a certain date in a pdf format. Everything works fine on my laptop with Linux, but when I set the project in the local server of our company, the name of the file is showing without a date.
Here is my code:

```
  template_name = 'pdf.html'
    template = get_template(template_name)
    html = template.render({"data": data, "date":date, "index":index})

    if 'DYNO' in os.environ:
        print('loading wkhtmltopdf path on heroku')
        WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = subprocess.Popen(
            ['which', os.environ.get('WKHTMLTOPDF_BINARY', 'wkhtmltopdf-pack')],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
    else:
        print('loading wkhtmltopdf path on localhost')
        WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = ('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf')

    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD)
    options = {
        'margin-bottom': '10mm',
        'footer-center': '[page]'
    }
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config, options=options)
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="otchet-{}.pdf"'.format(date)
    return response
```

when I download locally, the name of the file is - **otchet-2021-06-30.pdf**
but on server, it looks like - **otchet%20.pdf**
I have no idea, how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Use an f string.

```
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="otchet-{date}.pdf"'
```